# Add external Javascipt files on Ionic 5 / Angular 9 project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to add some jquery functions to my Ionic 5 / Angular 9 project.

I call the files from the angular.json file. Some of the functions work because I have installed Jquery and Bootstrap through npm.

But I don't know how to able to use the others.

These are the files

```
"scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/charts.js",
          "src/assets/js/colors.js",
          "src/assets/js/filters.js",
          "src/assets/js/global.js",
          "src/assets/js/idangerous.swiper.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/jqColorPicker.js",
          "src/assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/jquery-ui.js",
          "src/assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/jquery.canvasjs.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/jquery.countTo.js",
          "src/assets/js/jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/jquery.mixitup.js",
          "src/assets/js/jquery.viewportchecker.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/magnific.js",
          "src/assets/js/map.js",
          "src/assets/js/script.js",
          "src/assets/js/sorttable.js",
          "src/assets/js/wow.js"
        ]
      },
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 4):

You need to read this article thoroughly: https://angular.io/guide/using-libraries

In short for your case:

- Install the libraries using NPM or via direct js file inside assets/js
- Ensure the reference is added in the angular.json

  ```
   "scripts": [
     "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js",
     "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
     "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
   ]
  ```

Once done it will be **the equivalent of you adding it via a script tag**.

To use such libraries in your Angular/Ionic application you have several options:

Libraries that support named export:

```
import { myFunction } from 'theLibraryName';
```

Or

```
import myLibrary from 'theLibraryName';
```

If it is a legacy library try using it by adding declare statement in the class right after import statements, like so:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare const GIFEncoder: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-download-gif',
  templateUrl: 'download-gif.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['download-gif.page.scss']
})
export class DownloadGifPage {

  constructor(
    
  ) {
  }
  
}
```

As Angular documentation suggests you can declare such libraries manually by adding them to the global typings in src/typings.d.ts

**Update re legacy libraries that do not use export:**

Each js library has a different strategy of their initialization but in most cases, they end up adding a new object to the global execution context of your web-app (basically becomes a property to global window object).

So if you did the steps above and need to check if such a library is available for your codebase - you can just issues commands relevant for that library via dev console.

Here is an example I did for sortable.js:

[image]

Comment: I did read it. Now reading it again. So, if want to install sortable.js i will npm install sortable.js and then call it in angular.json? Plus sortable.js begins like this.    **(function($){$.extend({tablesorter:new...**  how will i declare var ????

Comment: let me expand the answer

Comment: Thanks Sergey trying it now thanks. What i dont understand is how to declare a function when -to me- has no name **(function($){$.extend({tablesorter:new...**

Comment: i am getting this error Sergey. **PS C:\Users\Simos\desktopNew> npm install sorttable.js --save
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: sorttable.js@latest**   i am trying to install sorttable.js

Comment: when i put an alert in the sorttable.js is shows as wanted. **(function($){
    alert('welcome3');**   So does than mean the functions should work right?

Comment: can you give a link to such library so i can try?

Comment: I use bootstrap and jquery and the files i posted. and this template http://preview.themeforest.net/item/nrgnetwork-responsive-social-network-template/full_screen_preview/12444086?_ga=2.63661736.646306547.1595501796-1669925477.1594761922

Comment: I will add some additional explanation to my answer its just I do not have access to actual js code of those libraries and if there is a particular library that does not work for you maybe you could create new question specifically for it? but see my updated answer

Comment: I did a new one. What i dont understand is why the alert plays but functions don't https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63051477/ionic-5-angular-9-project-doesnt-play-the-functions-but-does-alert-from-externa/63051624#63051624

Comment: i just want to use this **if($('#container-mix').length) {
  $('#container-mix').mixItUp(
   {
    animation: {
     duration: 400,
     effects: 'fade translateZ(-360px) stagger(34ms)',
     easing: 'ease'
    }
   }
  );};**       i use it inside a ngOninit() but i am getting an error mixItUp is not exist on type Jquery